# jTextfield with input from jList

Tags: java, swing, focus, jtextfield, jlist

I have a jTextfield for which I have to take input from jList. On FocusGained property,jList should appear exactly below jTextfield and jList should disappear on FocusLost property. I have done some coding but I am getting a problem in it. At FocusGained property,jList appears but aftr clicking on it, it goes to back side of other jTextfield which is below previous textfield.
Following is my Code:

```
private void txtAccountFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                       
    jScrollPane3.setLocation(txtAccount.getX(), txtAccount.getY()+txtAccount.getHeight());
    jScrollPane3.setVisible(true);    //scrollpane associated with list
    listAccount.setVisible(true);   //listAccount is jList
}

private void listAccountMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                         
    txtAccount.setText((String)listAccount.getSelectedValue());
    jScrollPane3.setVisible(false);  //scrollpane associated with list
    txtSalesLedger.requestFocus(); //it is next field
}
```

Comment: Please provide the code you suspect to be problematic or/and need help with.

Comment: foir better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: I can not add images because I am a new user.

Comment: @Ajinkya Jagtap then save that to the public web, and I (or any of user) can update your question with this image, btw, are you read SSCCE document, any of answer could be shots to the dark only

Answer (score 1):

Use a `JComboBox` instead of a `JTextField`.
You can call `JComboBox.setEditable( true )`, and then the `JComboBox` will have an editor `JTextField`. Exactly what you want, and the user can enter any text, but also the list box can be opened with the arrow icon. Moreover you can make the list automatically appear by calling `JComboBox.showPopup()`. If you add a focus listener to the JComboBox's editor text field, you can also show the popup from there when the user clicks on the text field. The popup list can be closed with the arrow icon.

Here's a sample code:

```
final JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( 
    new Object[] { "", "Item #1", "Another item", "Something else" } );

comboBox.setEditable( true );

comboBox.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addFocusListener( new FocusAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void focusGained( final FocusEvent event ) {
        comboBox.showPopup();
    }
} );
```

**Note:** The first item of the combo box is an empty string. I added that so that the editor text field of the combo box will not show any value initially. You can remove that if you want an initial value of course.

Comment: don't use hacks (like an empty string): instead set the model's selectedItem to null initially

Comment: The empty string is not just a hack to make no other items selected. It provides the possibility of selecting none of the items (from the list, not requiring the user to manually clear the field).

Comment: then a better user experience is to make it explicit, like a localized <nothing selected>

Comment: My form contains many fields like this. If I am using jCombobox instead of jList then it looks like too much spoon feeding. Thats why I was trying to use jList